# Exporting react-query wrappers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have 2 packages and react-query as dependency:

```
/UI
  /node_modules
    /common
/common
  /node_modules
    /react-query
```

In my common package, I have a few react-query wrappers that encapsulate some specific logic.

A schematic example of the wrapper:

```
export const useQuery = <
    TData = unknown,
    TError = unknown
    >(
        queryKey: QueryKey,
        queryFunction: QueryFunction<AxiosResponse<TData, any>>,
        options?: UseQueryOptions<TData, TError>
        ): UseQueryResult<TData, TError> => {
            return useQueryOriginal<TData, TError, TData>(
                queryKey,
                (context) => queryFunction(context).then(r => r.data),
                options);
        };
```

Now, in my UI package I want to create a concrete hook:

```
import { useQuery } from 'common';

const useMyConrecteQuery = () => useQuery(['key'], () => apiCall());
```

At this I'm getting the error:

```
The inferred type of 'useMyConcreteQuery' cannot be named without a reference to 'common/node_modules/react-query'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

I tried:

1. re-declare all used types in the common package, but that did not help
2. add ``declaration': true` to the tsconfig

Comment: Assuming that common is an NPM package, what do the typings (`.d.ts`) for your common package look like?

Comment: not sure if it is related but there is an open TypeScript issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42873

Comment: @dr11 I have similar error right now, have you solved your issue?

Comment: eventually, I did not find a good solution at that time, so I simply created a few custom interfaces to speed up..